# Sage 50 integration with PHP based web application

Tags: php, integration, sage50

We have created a web based application and are trying to integrate Sage 50 system with it. On doing some research we found Sage provides SDK for to access Sage functions pro-grammatically. Is there more options available and which is the best practice for this approach.

Comment: You could think about contacting Sage and asking them about it. They most likely get that sort of question a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a [link here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28507922/Run-SQL-Query-on-Sage-50-Database.html) explaining how this can be done.

It basically says that you can create a Connection string to connect to the Sage50 database and then fetch the data from it. From there you can handle the integration processes.

```
ConnectionString = "ODBC;DSN=" & DN & ";UID=" & UR & ";PWD=" & PW & ";DIR=" & DR & ";"
```

Where

This uses the real Version number not the year version number tacked onto  SageLine50v
Example for V2013
`'DN = "SageLine50v19"`

UserName
`'UR = "manager"`

Password
  `'PW = ""`

The path to the Data files this has \ACCDATA on the end of it

`'DR = "S:\ACCDATA"`

Let us know your findings.